# Running Complex Samples in R?

Tags: r, statistics, spss

I'm starting to use R more and would very much appreciate advice on how I would run a complex samples crosstab.

Here is the SPSS syntax:

```
CSTABULATE
 /PLAN FILE='D:\data\data2019.sav'
 /TABLES VARIABLES=income_b BY sex
 /CELLS POPSIZE COLPCT
 /STATISTICS SE CIN(95) DEFF COUNT
 /TEST ODDSRATIO INDEPENDENCE
 /MISSING SCOPE=TABLE CLASSMISSING=EXCLUDE.
```

Any suggestions on how to do this in the R, please?

Many thanks.

Comment: To answer your question correctly, one needs to understand `SPSS` which many of the `R` folks might not be aware of. Since you want an answer in R, I would suggest you to follow the R standard of asking questions. Read on how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) and show expected output based on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the **survey** package. Specifically the **svytable** function. Here is an example from the package documentation

```
  data(api)
  xtabs(~sch.wide+stype, data=apipop)

  dclus1<-svydesign(id=~dnum, weights=~pw, data=apiclus1, fpc=~fpc)
  summary(dclus1)

  (tbl <- svytable(~sch.wide+stype, dclus1))
  svychisq(~sch.wide+stype, dclus1)
  summary(tbl, statistic="Chisq")
  svychisq(~sch.wide+stype, dclus1, statistic="adjWald")
```